# Contour integral around circle - Complex Analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

***Exercise :***

> *Show that :*
>
> $$\frac{1}{2πi}\oint_{|z|=r} \frac{e^{1/z}}{z-1}dz = \Bigg\{\begin{matrix}
> 1-e & r<1\\ 
> 1 & r >1
> \end{matrix}
> $$

I came across this exercise while I was studying for my complex analysis semester exams and I would really appreciate any guidance, tips or thorough solution. I know I am not providing an attempt (probably the only time I have done so in all my questions) but I can't grasp on how to work depending on the *radius* $R$. Most integrals I've solved can be worked around with the *Theorem of Residues* or the *Trigonometric/General Integrals* techniques, but I cannot seem to work on this one. Maybe one idea is to work through poles and singular points.

I would really value a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea for the residues

$$z=0:\;\;\frac{e^{1/z}}{z-1}=-\frac1{1-z}\cdot e^{1/z}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!z^n}=$$

$$=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{(n-k)!z^{n-k}}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{(n-k)!z^{n-2k}}$$

The coefficient of $\;z^{-1}\;$ in the above is given by $\;n-2k=1\iff k=\cfrac{n-1}2\;$ , and thus $\;n\;$ must be odd, so we get that the coefficient for each such value of $\;n\;$ odd is $\;\frac1{\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)!}\;$ , and thus the whole wanted coefficient is

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}=-(e-1)=1-e$$

I think the residue at $\;z=1\;$ is much easier to calculate and I leave that to you.

Comment: Good morning and thanks so much for your answer. I wanted to ask something. I clearly understand the $z=0$ *series expansion* part. But I can't seem to get the coefficient thingy. If you have the time and don't mind, can you give a short explanation to me ? How does $z^{-1}$ play a role ?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Well, it is **precisely** the coefficient of $\;z^{-1}\;$ when doing a Laurent series around a pole that is going to determine the value of an integral on a closed curve containing only that pole... Have you studied yet The Residue Theorem for complex integrals?

Comment: We have studied 7 cases of a point $z_0$ for the *Residue* $Res(f,z_0)$, which have not mentioned about $z^{-1}$ (maybe our cases lead to that).

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos But then **you must know** what residue is! It is just the coefficient of $\;(z-z_0)^{-1}\;$ in the Laurent series around the pole $\;z_0\;$ ...!

Comment: Truth is, I know that, but my mind got stuck because we have't been referring to it a lot. I mean all the residue-related thorems and exercises we had been working on, was by cases, so in such a way I hadn't handled anything, but that's great because I've got my mind on something fresh here, so thanks so much !! Yep, it all makes sence, the countour integral for the coefficients in *Laurent Series* is the *Residue* of course. Sorry for being stuck on something rather simple, the series thingy though was hard enough. Any hint for $z=1$ ? Amazing help though mate !

Comment: If you take a closed curve enclosing *both* poles, at zero and at $\;1\;$ , then you need the residue *at* $\;Z=1\;$ , too...but this is easy, as you can simply calculate by means of a limit: $$\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)f(z)=\lim_{z\to1}e^{1/z}=e$$ and then you just add residues and etc.

Comment: Yes, true, hadn't checked the case. Now started solving it manually as well, you provided some great help so I really value it ! Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- If $r<1$, the only singularity is at $0$. Since 
  $$\frac{1}{z-1}=-\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n,$$
  you can conclude easily compute the Laurent series of $\frac{e^{1/z}}{z-1}$ and conclude.
- If $r>1$, you also have a singularity at $z=1$. Since $e^{1/z}$ is holomorphic at the neighborhood of $1$, you can easily compute the residue at $z=1$ using Cauchy formula.